# How to remove div container from HTML but not its content

Tags: javascript

I have this structure:

```
<div clas="page_cat_list">
    <div class="page_cat_row">
        <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
        <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
        <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
        <div class="clear_fix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="page_cat_row">
        <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
        <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
        <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
        <div class="clear_fix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I need it to look like this:

```
<div clas="page_cat_list">
    <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
    <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
    <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
    <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
    <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
    <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
</div>
```

I can insert JavaScript in the HTML, but I can not change these elements directly, because it's generated by some kind of function.

Comment: I can use display: none for clearfix, but I have to eliminate the page_cat_row somehow.

Comment: just append all `.page_cat_item` to `.page_cat_list` and remove `.pagecat_list>.page_cat_row` then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could arrive with this simple `js` approach:

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.page_cat_list');
var contents = container.querySelectorAll('.page_cat_row');
var newContent = '';

[].forEach.call(contents, function(cont) {
    newContent = newContent + cont.innerHTML;
})

container.innerHTML = newContent;
```

```html
<div class="page_cat_list">
    <div class="page_cat_row">
        <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
        <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
        <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
        <div class="clear_fix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="page_cat_row">
        <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
        <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
        <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
        <div class="clear_fix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI, using innerHTML will work as long as there are no events attached to the DOM nodes before you replace the content. If there are events attached, you blow them away.

Comment: @epascarello sure, since the point were _the content_ I focused on this simple way.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with a combination of `detach()` and `html()` in JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var ele = $('.page_cat_row').children().detach();
  $('.page_cat_row').remove();
  $('.page_cat_list').html(ele);
});
```

See the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w6gkf23d/

With this, you don't need to directly loop anything as JQuery does it all for you.

Note that you will still need to set the `clear_fix` class to `display:none`.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the elements and than loop over the children appending them to the parent element.

```js
(function() {

  var wrappers = document.querySelectorAll(".page_cat_row"); //grab the parent elements

  //Loop over the collection
  for (var i = wrappers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    //get the element and its parent
    var wrapperToBeRemoved = wrappers[i],
      parentNode = wrapperToBeRemoved.parentNode

    //loop over the children until they are all removed
    while (wrapperToBeRemoved.firstChild) {
      parentNode.insertBefore(wrapperToBeRemoved.firstChild,
        wrapperToBeRemoved);
    }

    //remove the wrapper from the collection
    parentNode.removeChild(wrapperToBeRemoved);

  }

}());
```

```css
.page_cat_row {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div clas="page_cat_list">
  <div class="page_cat_row">
    <div class="page_cat_item">1...</div>
    <div class="page_cat_item">2...</div>
    <div class="page_cat_item">3...</div>
    <div class="clear_fix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="page_cat_row">
    <div class="page_cat_item">4...</div>
    <div class="page_cat_item">5...</div>
    <div class="page_cat_item">6...</div>
    <div class="clear_fix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the easiest way to do this.

Move the first `childNode` to the parent until the wrapper element has children.

If you don't have text between the elements, you can use `wrapper.children.length` instead, because it's faster in that case.

```js
function removeElement(element) {
  element.parentElement.removeChild(element);
}

function removeWrapper(wrapper) {
  while (wrapper.childNodes.length) {
    wrapper.parentElement.appendChild(wrapper.childNodes[0]);
  }
  wrapper.parentElement.removeChild(wrapper);
}

var clrFix = document.querySelectorAll('.page_cat_row > .clear_fix');
for (var i = 0; i < clrFix.length; i++) {
  removeElement(clrFix[i]);
}

var cat_rows = document.querySelectorAll('.page_cat_list > .page_cat_row');
for (var i = 0; i < cat_rows.length; i++) {
  removeWrapper(cat_rows[i]);
}
```

```css
.page_cat_row {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="page_cat_list">
  <div class="page_cat_row">
    <div class="page_cat_item">1...</div>
    <div class="page_cat_item">2...</div>
    <div class="page_cat_item">3...</div>
    <div class="clear_fix">fix</div>
  </div>
  <div class="page_cat_row">
    <div class="page_cat_item">4...</div>
    <div class="page_cat_item">5...</div>
    <div class="page_cat_item">6...</div>
    <div class="clear_fix">fix</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e9fvjaqe/)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use unwrap.

```
$('.page_cat_item').unwrap();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$( "#divid" ).load(function() {
$( this ).removeClass( "page_cat_row" );
});
```

Comment: OP did not ask how to remove a class, but how to remove the element.